# Equation for dice probability

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Is there a known equation to calculate the probability of $x$ number of $y$ sided dice $z$ number of times and getting matches of $n$ number (i.e. $2$ of a kind, $3$ of a kind, $4$ of a kind, etc.)?

I've read lots of answers that solve "odds of rolling doubles on various sides of dice," but none that take these 4 variable into account.

Comment: So you like to now the probability to have $5$ '3' appearing when you throw $10$ dice that have $6$ faces, for example ?

Comment: @Zubzub yup! Exactly!

Comment: The probability is given by the binomial distribution $B(p,n)$ 
where $p = \frac{1}{\# \text{faces}}$, $n$ the number of dice you throw. Note that here I assume that all dices are fair which gives the same probability for any number to appear.

Comment: @Zubzub I'm reading the wikipedia on Binomial Distribution now. How does "re rolling" factor into the equation?

Comment: That isn’t quite what you asked in the question above. It appears there that you’re looking for the probability of, say, five of *any* number appear on a roll of 10d6, not five of a specific number. The binomial distribution is a good starting point for computing this, but there’s a bit more to coming up with an answer to your original question.

Comment: @amd I'm only looking for a specific number in the context of determining matches. I don't care which number, as long as it's doubles, or triples, etc.

Comment: Again, that’s a different question than what Zubzub proposed. Take a simple case: the probability of getting a pair of sixes on 2d6 is $1/36$, but the probability of getting *any* double whatsoever is six times that.